# How do I change the Entry value to int in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a calculator that adds 10 to the number using tkinter.
But I had to get the entry price in int format, so I used get method.
I keep getting the following error message. What's the problem?

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()



a=Entry(window)
a.pack()
b=a.get()
c=int(b)

result2=Label(window,text="")
result2.pack()

def Button_Press():
    global c
    result=c+10
    result2.config(text=result)

button=Button(window,command=Button_Press())
button=pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Here's the error text.

```
c=int(b)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: in python you can use an `IntVar()` and i dont think error would be produced again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Has show you that the c is `''`(a string which length is zero).The code seems to be `int('')`.That's why it will raise exception.
Your code could be:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

a = Entry(window)
a.insert("end", "0") # just insert a str "0"
a.pack()
b = a.get()
c=int(b)
print(c)

result2 = Label(window, text="")
result2.pack()


def Button_Press():
    result = c + 10
    result2.config(text=result)


button = Button(window, command=Button_Press) # there is no "()"
button.pack() # not button = pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `a.get()` and conversion to int should happen inside the Button_Press function rather than only only as the start of the code when the Entry widget is empty.